# Funções recursivas em C++: exemplos

Tags: c++, funções, recursão

Estou a iniciar a aprendizagem em C++ e, de momento, debruço-me sobre as funções recursivas. Já vi alguns exemplos interessantes, como o cálculo do factorial de um número, mas gostaria de ver outros exemplos. Espero que não considerem esta pergunta muito ampla. Trata-se apenas de ver e partilhar outros exemplos que podem ser uteis a quem está a aprender a linguagem. Obrigado!

Comment: Posso colocar aqui um exemplo para dinamizar a minha pergunta?

Comment: este link contém versões de função para calcular se um número é primo ou não em tempo de compilação, requer conhecimento avançado de c++: https://gist.github.com/oblitum/5692062

Answer (score 1):

Eis um programa que escrevi há algum tempo com o objectivo de ensinar funções, em particular exemplificar a diferença entre funções normais (usando um algoritmo iterativo) e recursivas. Neste caso, pretende-se calcular os valores da sequência de Fibonnaci (ver [aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequ%C3%AAncia_de_Fibonacci) por exemplo).

---

```
/*
 *       Sequência de Fibonacci  
 *       (de forma normal e de forma recursiva; esta última é bem mais lenta)
 *
 */


#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned long long fibonacci(const unsigned int n){
    unsigned long long resultado;
    if (n==0)
        resultado=0;
    else if (n==1)
        resultado=1;
        else{
            unsigned long long tabela[n+1];
            tabela[0]=0;
            tabela[1]=1;
            for (auto i=2;i<=n;++i){
                tabela[i]=tabela[i-2]+tabela[i-1];
            }
            resultado=tabela[n];
        }           
    return resultado;
}

unsigned long long fibonacciRecursive(const unsigned int n){
    if (n==0)
        return 0;
    else if (n==1)
         return 1;
        else
            return(fibonacciRecursive(n-2)+fibonacciRecursive(n-1));
}


int main(){
    unsigned int numero;

    do{
        cout << "Escolha numero (0 para terminar): ";
        cin >> numero;
        cout << "O numero de fibonnaci de ordem " << numero << " e " << fibonacci(numero) << endl;
        cout << "O numero de fibonnaci de ordem " << numero << " e " << fibonacciRecursive(numero) << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }while(numero!=0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 para o exemplo. Porque usa o unisgned long long em vez de int?

Comment: @CapitãoAhab Ambos os tipos fundamentais são integrais mas o `unsigned long long` permite lidar com valores substancialmente superiores que o `int`. No standard do C++ é especificado que este último tem uma representação de pelo menos 16 bits, ao passo que o que foi utilizado no meu programa tem pelo menos 64 bits. A gama de valores em concreto que cada um dos tipos admite depende da implementação e do compilador. Fazendo sizeof(tipo) permite verificar o tamanho (em Bytes) dos mesmos. No meu caso, `int` ocupa 4 e `unsigned long long` ocupa 8.